# Is there a built-in, locale-aware PHP function/class to output "1 hour", "25 minutes", "3 days" etc.?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, locale

I have already coded a function like this on my own, which just takes two timestamps, converts them to Unix seconds, subtracts one from the other, and then determines how many minutes/hours/whatever specified to calculate based on those seconds.

Problems:

1. My function only outputs English and German. If it exists, I would like to get output for all the other languages/locales as well.
2. While it normally doesn't matter, due to the nature of a "vague" string such as a "1 year" or "7 months", for very large time spans, my method doesn't handle e.g. leap years correctly. If I have selected the parameter to force "days" as unit, and it's many years between the two timestamps, the number of days will certainly be off by many days.

I'm fairly sure that PHP's DateTime class or something has this, but I've looked and been unable to find any such feature. So maybe it doesn't exist.

I want something like:

```
echo human_friendly_time_string('2020-02-09 00:00:00', '2020-02-10 00:00:00') . PHP_EOL; // No time unit forced, so it picks the most reasonable one.
echo human_friendly_time_string('2020-02-09 00:00:00', '2020-02-10 00:00:00', 'hours') . PHP_EOL; // Force hours.
echo human_friendly_time_string('2020-02-09 00:00:00', '2020-02-10 00:00:00', 'days') . PHP_EOL; // Force days.
echo human_friendly_time_string('2020-02-09 00:00:00', '2020-02-10 00:00:00', 'minutes') . PHP_EOL; // Force minutes.
echo human_friendly_time_string('2020-02-09 00:00:00', '2020-02-10 00:00:00', 'days', 1) . PHP_EOL; // Force days, and force one decimal.
```

To output (for English language/locale):

```
1 day
24 hours
1 day
720 minutes
1.0 day
```

Again, I already have coded this myself for English and German, so I'm not interested in PHP code that duplicates this. I only wonder if this is built into PHP and, if so, how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) which has a [`diff`](http://php.net/datetime.diff) method that can return a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval) object with the relevant information.

For example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2020-02-08 12:43:18');
$date2 = new DateTime('2020-02-10 00:00:00');

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

echo
  $diff->days, " days,", $diff->h, " hours,", $diff->i, " minutes,", $diff->s, " seconds.";
// Gives you: 1 days,11 hours,16 minutes,42 seconds.
```

For i18n there is of course [`intl`](http://php.net/intl) which has a rules-based formatter that can handle duration as well.

For example:

```
// Calculate the number of seconds between two dates using DateTime
$date1 = new DateTime('2020-02-08 12:43:18');
$date2 = new DateTime('2020-02-10 00:00:00');

// Most verbosely expressed as...
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

$seconds = $diff->days * 24 * 60 * 60;
$seconds += $diff->h * 60 * 60;
$seconds += $diff->i * 60;
$seconds += $diff->s;

// Or more simply just
$seconds = $date2->getTimestamp() - $date1->getTimestamp();

// Hand it to the formatter
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::DURATION); // set your locale here
echo $fmt->format($seconds);
// Gives you 35:16:42
```

There is of course an [`IntlCalendar`](http://php.net/intlcalendar) object as well that can do this with more granularity as you expect in your example above.

Here's an example:

```
$cal1 = IntlCalendar::createInstance('Europe/London', 'de_DE');
$cal2 = IntlCalendar::createInstance('Europe/London', 'de_DE');
$cal1 = $cal1->fromDateTime('2020-02-08 12:43:18');
$cal2 = $cal2->fromDateTime('2020-02-10 00:00:00');
$time = $cal2->getTime();

echo
$cal1->fieldDifference($time, IntlCalendar::FIELD_YEAR), " years, ",
$cal1->fieldDifference($time, IntlCalendar::FIELD_MONTH), " months, ",
$cal1->fieldDifference($time, IntlCalendar::FIELD_DAY_OF_MONTH), " days, ",
$cal1->fieldDifference($time, IntlCalendar::FIELD_HOUR_OF_DAY), " hours, ",
$cal1->fieldDifference($time, IntlCalendar::FIELD_MINUTE), " minutes, ",
$cal1->fieldDifference($time, IntlCalendar::FIELD_SECOND), " seconds.";

// Gives you: 0 years, 0 months, 1 days, 11 hours, 16 minutes, 42 seconds.
```

Comment: Well, I can't help but notice that you hardcode all strings such as "years" or "minutes"...

Comment: Right, internationalization isn't about translation. It's about format. Different locales require things like numbers, dates, and currencies to be formatted a certain way. What Intl can do for you is help ease the process of taking in those formatted inputs, and spitting out the proper formatted outputs, but it won't translate words for you. For that you need to write your own translation tables and use something like gnu [`gettext`](http://php.net/gettext) to process them. While these are related matters, they are generally two separate problems with separate solutions.

Comment: The other locale-related features in PHP do output text. For example, the "spellout" one which says "ninenty-nine" in English and all other languages. Essentially, the main point of asking this question was to *avoid* having to make such manual translation tables for these ultra-common things which are quite reasonable to expect to be built in, and which are for other things (but apparently not for this).

Comment: Sure, the SPELLOUT ruleset does indeed provide words, but not as translations. Rather they are the result of formatting a digit number into a spelled word(s). Of course, it would be nice if it could provide you with the same contextual formatting of your time difference here to include qualifying periods. Perhaps there is some obscure formatter rule in libicu that does do that. I'm just not aware of it. But libicu is **huge**. It's actually bigger than the entire php project itself. So it may not even be available in php since php only has a partial implementation. Sorry I wasn't more helpful.

Comment: In a way, I guess it's a good thing if it doesn't exist (or doesn't exist in PHP). At least that way, I won't have completely wasted so much time making my own function! But maybe somebody else might know where it's hidden. (It took me about 20 years to find out about NumberFormatter's existence at all!)